# Array from webservice

Tags: php

I have difficulty in reading the array below. I want to get the value of any existing name. please help me to solve this problem. I say thank you for your help.

```
Array
(
    [Attribute] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => ContactName
                    [value] => Ridwan
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Email
                    [value] => Ridwan@yahoo.com
                )

        )

)
```

Results above submissions of webservice as below.

```
     <ContactAttr>
        <Attribute>
           <name>ContactName</name>
           <value>Ridwan</value>
        </Attribute>
         <Attribute>
           <name>Email</name>
           <value>Ridwan@yahoo.com</value>
        </Attribute>
     </ContactAttr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$xml = ...; // Your XML

$sx = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach($sx->Attribute as $attr) {
    echo $attr->name,': ',$attr->value,'<br />';
}
?>
```

Outputs:

> ContactName: Ridwan
>
> Email: Ridwan@yahoo.com